# How to make a different textview in each fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview

I've made 3 sliding tabs using fragments, and I want each fragment to show a text view. My question is, how do I do that? Now it writes "fragment #" in each tab, but what about a textview instead? I wanna write a lot of text in each tab.
This is how I made it write the fragment number:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
    TextView tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
    tvTitle.setText("Fragment #" + mPage); //Here
    return view;
```

So instead I want 3 textviews; one in each tab

EDIT:
Sliding fragments:

```
public class SampleFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
private String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "Tab1", "Tab2", "Tab3" };

public SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return PAGE_COUNT;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return PageFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    // Generate title based on item position
    return tabTitles[position];
 }
}
```

FRAGMENT:

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment {
public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";

private int mPage;

public static PageFragment newInstance(int page) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
    PageFragment fragment = new PageFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mPage = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
}

// Inflate the fragment layout we defined above for this fragment
// Set the associated text for the title
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
    TextView tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
    tvTitle.setText("Fragment #" + mPage);
    return view;
 }
}
```

I get this:

[image]

I want to write something different in each tab. I mean different textviews, so instead of fragment#1, I wanna write my own text (and the same goes for the other tabs)

Comment: Add textview in Xml files.

Comment: So one XML file for each textview?

Comment: Every fragment should have it's own xml. Show the code where you have created three sliding fragments.

Comment: You use a TabLayout for setting the tab titles, not fragments

Comment: You say you want each fragment to show a textview and from the look of it, you're code already does that

Comment: https://guides.codepath.com/android/google-play-style-tabs-using-tablayout

Comment: In this way,You won't be able to do anything with your fragments.Let me give you an example

Comment: Have uploaded my fragment code

Comment: It appears that your code does exactly what you are asking. So apparently I don't understand your question. Please provide a screen shot of what this code does and describe how this differs from what you want.

Comment: You are already setting the text of each TextView and tab. Just change the text to whatever you wish.

Comment: I know I have put the text "Fragment#", but that's for them all. I want something different for each. For example I wanna write "Hello" in the first tab, and "Hey" in the second, and "Bye" in the third. I haven't done that

Comment: My problem is that I can only let it write the same text in all tabs

Answer (score 0):

You already have the framework that allows you to set different text for each page. The easiest way to customize the text is to modify your `newInstance()` method:

```
public static PageFragment newInstance(String message) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_MSG, message);
    PageFragment fragment = new PageFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
```

}

(Remember to create the `ARG_MSG` constant which is similar to the `ARG_PAGE` constant that you already have.)

Now you need to get the `ARG_MSG` and set the `TextView` to display it. This is very similar to what you are already doing with the page number. I will leave the details for you to figure out.

Comment: Ok, but what should I write inside the method  tvTitle.setText();, and where I should I write the text I want to appear?

Comment: @hudhud It is very similar to what you have now. First you need to get the text from the Fragment's arguments. This is similar to how you get `mPage` in `onCreate()`. I suggest that you create a different variable with a descriptive name to store the text. Also, this variable needs to have a different type than `mPage` does. Next, you use this variable to set the text of your `TextView`. I won't do this for you. You need to figure out some of this yourself.

Comment: I've done these now and now each tab is an empty textview. Where should I write the text for each tab?

Comment: @hudhud Look at `SampleFragmentPagerAdapter` as you posted it here. Can you see how the tab titles are set? If not, I suggest you read more about `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

Comment: Yes I can, but I can't make a switch in it as I can't change the text from there. I know I can change the getItem method with a swith(position), but what should I write in the cases? What should they return?

Comment: @hudhud "I can't make a switch in it" I'm not sure what this means. Where are you thinking of making a switch? As for the `getItem()` method, I suggest doing something similar to the tab titles: create an array with the text to show and then use the array to create a fragment. Alternatively, you could create an array of fragments in the `SampleFragmentPagerAdapter` constructor and just return the correct fragment directly. This avoids creating lots of fragments with the exact same data.

Comment: @hudhud If you need any more help, please post a new question.